# how to create rar/zipfile and download

Tags: php, javascript

Hi frnds can anyone tel me how to Create a Zip File Using PHP?
Actually i am having 10 files with boxes,if i select more than one check box that files should get zip/rar and i am able to save that in some path..

Please can anyone help in this solution as i am new to php

Answer (score 2):

```
$zip_name = 'path/to/final.zip'; //the real path of your final zip file on your system
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: filename="' . $zip_name . '"');
header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_name));
readfile($zip_name);
exit();
```

Comment: path/to/final.zip which is this path? i want to install winzip in my system? actually i am using winrar..

Comment: edited my answer about the path. no, you don't need to install any third-party software. ZipArchive is PHP's built-in Zip extension. You can use it out of the box in PHP 5.2.0+

Comment: zip is creating but whatever files i am selecting in checkbox that files not coming into zipfolder..wat is the problem?

Comment: Note: my code is an example only. These files are selectable via a HTML form? What's the name of your checkboxes?

Comment: actually i am getting files in array one by one that name is
$file_name //here i will get all the files from where i am selecting checkboxes

Comment: fine, and when you stepping through this array with foreach (like in my example) you cannot add actual files to your zip?

Comment: i am adding actual files like($file_name as $file)
then wat is the solution for adding seleting files in to that zip folder?

Comment: did you checked the files against file_exists()? if files exists you can add them with $zip->addFile($file); like in the example

Comment: yes i checking file exisist as like below even its not working
$path= "./upload/".$file_name;
if(file_exists($path))
{
foreach($file_name as $file)

{
    $zip->addFile($file_name);
}

Comment: $file_name is an array? i don't think so.

Comment: You can't concatenate a string and an array here: $path= "./upload/".$file_name; so $path cannot exists here: if(file_exists($path)) { ...

Answer (score 1):

```
// This example creates a ZIP file archive test.zip and add the file /path/to/index.txt. as newname.txt. 
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('/path/to/index.txt', 'newname.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: wht is that test.zip
also i dint get ('/path/to/index.txt','newname.txt');
actually i want to create zip for word document

Answer (score -1):

```
//include your connection file
//$file_names[] get your files array
//$error = "";      //error holder
//$file_path='set your image path' folder to load files
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
{ // Checking ZIP extension is available
    if(count($file_names) > 0)
    {   
        // Checking files are selected
        $zip = new ZipArchive();            // Load zip library 
        $zip_name = time().".zip";          // Zip name
        if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){       // Opening zip file to load files
            $error .=  "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time<br/>";
        }
        foreach($file_names as $file){  
            $zip->addFile($file_path.$file);            // Adding files into zip
        }
        $zip->close();  
        if(file_exists($zip_name))
        {
            // push to download the zip
            header('Content-type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
            readfile($zip_name);

            // remove zip file is exists in temp path
            unlink($zip_name);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $error .= "* Please select file to zip <br/>";
    }
}
else
{
    $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension<br/>";
}
?>
```